# CodeIgniter Query to Array wrong Result in REST Controller

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, rest

I'm testing the REST Module of CodeIgniter,
here is my simple GET Function:

```
    function test_get()
{
    if(!$this->get('id'))
    {
        $this->response(NULL, 400);
    }

    $query = $this->db->query('select * from test');
    $users = $query->result();

    $user = @$users[$this->get('id')];

    if($user)
    {
        $this->response($user, 200); // 200 being the HTTP response code
    }

    else
    {
        $this->response(array('error' => 'User could not be found'), 404);
    }
}
```

It works so far, but I'm not sure why I'm getting the id 2 as a result when I open http://.../test/id/1

```
<xml><id>2</id><attribut1>Testdata</attribut1><attribut2>asdfasdf</attribut2><testcol>asf</testcol></xml>
```

When I open http://.../test/id/2 I'm getting the the id 3 as a result.

Shouldn't that http://.../test/id/1 -> id 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an off-by-one issue.  You're indexing the `$users` array (which is zero-based), but your IDs are 1-based.  You'll have even worse issues when your user IDs have gaps (you'll be off by random increments, rather than just 1).  Try this instead:

```
function test_get()
{
    if(!$this->get('id'))
    {
        $this->response(NULL, 400);
    }

    $user = $this->db->where('id', $this->get('id'))->get('test')->first_row();

    if($user)
    {
        $this->response($user, 200); // 200 being the HTTP response code
    }

    else
    {
        $this->response(array('error' => 'User could not be found'), 404);
    }
}
```

Comment: oh sure, arrays are zero based! Your example is the solution. Thanks a lot :)